# Create a custom icon for <b:navLink>

Tags: jsf, icons, bootsfaces

I am trying to use Bootsfaces for one of my hobby project.
Bootsfaces provide option to add Icon to button and Nav bar Links.

I want to create a custom icon and want to add that to a Button.

I searched Bootsfaces.net for documentation but unable to get proper answer for the question.

somethings like

[image]

Can some one help me understanding how it works.

> EDIT

```
<b:navBar brand="My Club" brandHref="#" inverse="true" fixed="top">
<b:navbarLinks>
        <b:navLink value="About Us" href="#"></b:navLink>
        <b:navLink value="Updates" href="#"></b:navLink>
        <b:dropMenu value="Contact us" >
           <b:navLink value="Email" href="mailto:abc@xyz.com" icon="envelope"></b:navLink>
           <b:navLink></b:navLink>
           <b:navLink header="Social Media"></b:navLink>
           <b:navLink value="Facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/Page"></b:navLink>
           <b:navLink value="Group" href="http://www.facebook.com/URL"></b:navLink>
           <b:navLink value="Twitter" href="http://www.twitter.com/GROUP"></b:navLink>
        </b:dropMenu>
        <b:dropMenu value="Sign in ">
            <h:form >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <b:inputText placeholder="Email" fieldSize="sm" />
                    <!--input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"/-->
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <b:inputText placeholder="Password" fieldSize="sm" />
                </div> 
            #{' '}
            <b:commandButton action="a" value="Sign in"
                    look="success" icon="chevron-right" iconAlign="right" />
            </h:form>
        </b:dropMenu>
    </b:navbarLinks>
</b:navBar>
```

[image: sample]

Here you can see Email has Envelop icon, Similarly i need to have Icon for FB and Twitter

Comment: Can you provide some code so we can see what you've done so far?

Answer (score 2):

That's a feature we have to implement yet. CommandButtons support GlyphIcons and (starting with BootsFaces 0.6.5) FontAwesome icons, but not arbitrary icons. I've opened an issue on the project page: https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/65.